# nodejs- unable to return result to controller function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

From my Model, I fetch some articles from a MySQL database for a user.

**Model**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'sampleUser',
    password: '',
    database: 'sampleDB'
});

fetchArticles: function (user, callback) {
    var params = [user.userId];
    var query = `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE userId = ? LOCK IN SHARE MODE`;
    db.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            return connection.query(query, params, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function () {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
                //console.log(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This is working and the function fetches the result needed. But it's not returning the result to the controller function (I am returning it but I'm not able to fetch it in the controller function. I guess, I did something wrong here).

When I did `console.log(result)` this is what I got.

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    status: 'New',
    article_code: 13362,
    created_date: 2017-10-22T00:30:00.000Z,
    type: 'ebook'} ]
```

My controller function looks like this:

```
var Articles = require('../models/Articles');
exports.getArticle = function (req, res) {

    var articleId = req.body.articleId;
    var article = {
        userId: userId
    };

    Articles.fetchArticles(article, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'no data found' });
        }
        else {
            res.json({ success: true, articles: rows });
        }
    });
};
```

Can anyone help me figure out what mistakes I made here?
I'm pretty new to nodejs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you're not calling the `callback` function, anywhere.
Here's the adjusted code:

```
fetchArticles: function (user, callback) {
    var params = [user.userId];
    var query = `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE userId = ? LOCK IN SHARE MODE`;
    db.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            // An error. Ensure `callback` gets called with the error argument.
            return callback(err);
        }

        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                // An error. Ensure `callback` gets called with the error argument.
                return callback(err);
            }

            return connection.query(query, params, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    // An error.
                    // Rollback
                    connection.rollback(function () {
                        // Once the rollback finished, ensure `callback` gets called 
                        // with the error argument.
                        return callback(err);
                    });
                } else {
                  // Query success. Call `callback` with results and `null` for error.
                  //console.log(result);
                  return callback(null, result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

There's no point in throwing errors inside the callbacks on the `connection` methods, since these functions are async.
Ensure you pass the error to the `callback` instead, and stop execution *(using the `return` statement)*.

One more thing, without knowing the full requirements of this:
I'm not sure you need transactions for just fetching data from the database, without modifying it; so you can just do the `query()` and skip on using any `beginTransaction()`, `rollback()` and `commit()` calls.

Comment: I do need transactions as per the project requirement. Your code works but can you tell me where to do commit() while using the code you gave? @Mihai Potra

Comment: Normally you'd use the `commit()` in the last branch, instead of calling `callback` with the `result`, like so: 
   } else {
     // Query success.
     connection.commit(function (err) {
       if (err) {
         // I guess we need rollback for failed commits too.
         connection.rollback(function() {
           callback(err);
         });
       } else {
         // Commit successful as well.
         callback(null, results);
       }
     });
   }